# Selecting the proper item in a select list when the form is populated before the list

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a form for editing customers with a cities list specified through a select element. The real form has a lot of lists, however, this will do for now.

The form is populated by making a rest api call called /customer/{customerId}.

The list is populated by making a rest api call called /cities.

The calls are made in sequence in the controller using $http.get to get the cities and the other one via a $resource get (not in the code snippet below).

The problem is that in case the call to get the customer data for comes back first, the form selects the first city in the list instead of the right city.

Here are some code snippets:

html:

```
<select id="Select3" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.CityId">
    <option ng-repeat="j in Cities" value="{{j.CityId}}">{{j.City}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('customerInfoCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$location', 'CustomerApi', function ($scope, $http, $modal, $location, CustomerApi) {
    $http.get('../api/v1/cities').success(function (data) {
        $scope.Cities = data;
    });

    $scope.formData = CustomerApi.get({ id: $scope.customerId }, function () {
        ...
    });     
  ....
```

How do I fix this? Keep in mind that the form has lots of lists. Is there a pattern that can be applied systematically?

I know about `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$apply(fn)`. Should I call one of these in the success function for the call that gets the cities?

Thanks

An update:

Converting to ng-options seems to do the trick. I have to do more testing.

```
<select id="Select3" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.CityId" ng-options="j.CityId as j.City for j in Cities">
</select>
```

Another update:

I created a plnkr where you can see the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/Se8OIuxYBv4QXeH3Jgqh?p=preview

Comment: Maybe async queue is a solution?

Comment: You should put this request on a factory to return a promise, then resolve that promise in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make sure that some data loads before other, use the callback function you get when using both of your get() methods.
So if you wanted to load cities first, it could be something like that:

```
$http.get(../api/v1/cities').success(function (data) {
    $scope.Cities = data;
    //now that the cities are loaded, you can loead something else here. 
     $scope.formData = CustomerApi.get({ id: $scope.customerId }, function () {
    //this will always be loaded after cities
    });   
    $scope.loadSmthElse....  
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have about 15 lists on the form.

Comment: `success` method is deprecated, so use `then` instead

Comment: Maybe put all data gathering stuff in a service (or split it among several services) and then use that service in your controller?